# Why doesn't my wave movement code account for the game object's initial position?

Tags: unity

I want an object to move like wave. Currently, when I start the game the object's position doesn't account for its initial position. How would I fix this?

```
float amplitudeX = 5.0f;
float amplitudeY = 2.5f;
float omegaX = 0.5f;
float omegaY = 2.5f;
float index;

public void Update() {
    index += Time.deltaTime;
    float x = amplitudeX*Mathf.Cos (omegaX*index);
    float y = Mathf.Abs (amplitudeY*Mathf.Sin (omegaY*index));
    transform.localPosition= new Vector3(x,y,0);
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? If you add some more details, I can try to edit it for you.  Thanks!

Comment: @ Jesse Williams ,I've try to move object like wave or ziczac.it work proper but object position not start move with it's initial position.

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the initial position by setting the `localPosition` directly. You probably want to instead either use the calculated value as a velocity, which I believe would be applied to the rigid body component, or you could calculate the translation manually. That could be done by saving the original initial position at the `Start` method and adding your wave position to that position. So something along the lines of

```
public void Start() {
    InitialPosition = transform.localPosition;
}

public void Update() {
    transform.localPosition = InitialPosition + WaveMovement;
}
```